# DocuSign REST API bulk recipient transactions not showing in response

Tags: docusignapi

I have issues with getting the ID for the newly created envelopes when using the bulk send feature.

I'm using a template that has a bulk recipient signer (from a CSV file). 
I've managed to create with success a draft envelope with a bulk recipient signer based on the template, to pass the CSV file to the envelope and to change the status to 'sent' in order to trigger the sending of an envelope for each recipient.

The issue is that the response returned from sending the envelope doesn't contains the '**bulkRecipientTransactions**' element (the CSV file contains 2 signers).

Below you can see a response sample:

```
 <envelopeUpdateSummary xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <bulkEnvelopeStatus>
    <batchId>97ef8125-b305-4de7-837b-d89c36bd994e</batchId>
    <batchSize>2</batchSize>
    <bulkEnvelopesBatchUri>/bulk_envelopes/97ef8125-b305-4de7-837b-d89c36bd994e</bulkEnvelopesBatchUri>
    <failed>0</failed>
    <queued>2</queued>
    <sent>0</sent>
    <submittedDate>2015-07-24T07:10:18.9900000Z</submittedDate>
  </bulkEnvelopeStatus>
</envelopeUpdateSummary>
```

The same result came back when i've used the DocuSign API explorer for creating & sending a bulk recipient envelope  - no '**bulkRecipientTransactions**' element.

Also I've tried to check the status of one bulk send batch (***/accounts/{accountId}/bulk_envelopes/{batchId}***), but I've got as a result only the general batch info's - the element '**bulkEnvelopes**' was missing!

```
 <bulkEnvelopeStatus xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <batchId>97ef8125-b305-4de7-837b-d89c36bd994e</batchId>
  <batchSize>2</batchSize>
  <bulkEnvelopesBatchUri>/bulk_envelopes/97ef8125-b305-4de7-837b-d89c36bd994e</bulkEnvelopesBatchUri>
  <endPosition>2</endPosition>
  <failed>0</failed>
  <nextUri/>
  <previousUri/>
  <queued>0</queued>
  <resultSetSize>0</resultSetSize>
  <sent>2</sent>
  <startPosition>0</startPosition>
  <submittedDate>2015-07-24T07:10:18.9900000Z</submittedDate>
  <totalSetSize>2</totalSetSize>
</bulkEnvelopeStatus>
```

For all the workflow I've used the REST API v2 using C# and xml.

Comment: Hmm bulk send is a new feature and I haven't had a chance to try it out yet.  Sometimes I've seen DocuSign bugs based on the content type, as a test can you try sending the equivalent in JSON instead of XML to see if there's a difference?

Comment: @Ergin I've did a test using JSON instead of XML but with same results for both cases (elements still missing). For the change status method the issue can be easily reproduced using the REST API Explorer.

Comment: can you send me your developer accountID, I want to check your sandbox account and make sure Bulk Send is enabled.  ergin (dot) dervisoglu [at] docusign.com

Comment: Hello Ergin - I've sent the accountID via email. Please note that I've checked and the bulk feature is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

When you use /accounts/{accountId}/bulk_envelopes/{batchId} to get envelopes, you need specify queryString ?include=(all,failed,queued,sent).otherwise, you may not get any envelopes list result